# iOS view controller loaded twice old web view being referenced sometimes when scanning bluetooth barcode scanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I am creating an application that reads data from a socket bluetooth barcode scanner (Socket Mobile) and injects the string into a web view. My controller can be loaded more than one time during the application. This is where the issue is happening. It appears sometimes the barcode scanning still has a reference to the wrong web view the 2nd time it loads. (Nil object ref)

I have the following in my view controller's .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[StoreWebViewController checkAndPrependProtocolForUrl:self.storeUrl]]]];
 }

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ScanApi=[[ScanApiHelper alloc]init];
    [ScanApi setDelegate:self];
    [ScanApi open];
    ScanApiConsumer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.2 target:self selector:@selector(onBarcodeTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)onBarcodeTimer: (NSTimer*)theTimer{
    if(theTimer==ScanApiConsumer){
        [ScanApi doScanApiReceive];
    }
}

 //called when scan happens
-(void) onDecodedDataResult:(long)result device:(DeviceInfo *)device decodedData:(ISktScanDecodedData*)decodedData
{
    if(SKTSUCCESS(result))
    {
        NSLog(@"SCAN: %p", self.webView);
    }

}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.webView = nil;
}
```

in .h (relevant parts)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ScanApiHelper* ScanApi;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer* ScanApiConsumer;
```

1st load as I scan:

```
2015-10-08 16:05:08.368 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x15cd3c6f0
2015-10-08 16:05:09.367 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x15cd3c6f0
2015-10-08 16:05:11.168 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x15cd3c6f0
```

2nd load as I scan:

```
2015-10-08 16:05:38.670 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x15ee5ddb0
2015-10-08 16:05:40.269 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x15ee5ddb0
2015-10-08 16:05:41.168 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x0 //OLD WEB VIEW
2015-10-08 16:05:43.269 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x15ee5ddb0
2015-10-08 16:05:44.368 PHP POS[2646:971844] SCAN: 0x0 //OLD WEB VIEW
```

Is there a way to fix this? I am not sure how it has references to both objects...The timer doesn't seem to be running twice; as I scan and only get one NSLog entry

EDIT:

Here is how I create StoreWebViewController; which can happen multiple times.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"continueToStore"])
    {
        StoreWebViewController *controller = (StoreWebViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.storeUrl = [StoreUrlViewController checkAndPrependProtocolForStoreUrl:self.storeUrl.text];
    }
}
```

Comment: 0x0 isn't the old webview, it's `nil`.

Comment: Naming your variables in upper case is confusing.

Comment: It looks like your controller is being _created_ multiple times, not just presented. The logs with the `nil` webview (I guess) are from a VC which is still sticking around, but whose view is not on-screen. The view was unloaded and released its subviews, of which the webview was one. Make sure you're not creating multiples of this controller where you don't mean to.

Comment: 0x0 is the old web view as I set it to `nil` for testing. Before I did that it was referencing the old web view. I want multiple views though...As a user can go back and pick a new url to load. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Also it is NOT just the web view that is a bad reference. The entire self object is a reference to the previous StoreWebViewController. I think I need to find a way to remove all references when the view controller is removed from view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was even after the view was destroyed the timer from the previous object was still running. Adding the below code to viewDidDisappear fixes it

```
[ScanApiConsumer invalidate];
ScanApiConsumer = nil;
```